# Why do I get an unneeded column in code first created table?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I don't understand why EF creates a nullable `TemplateTask_Id` column in my `TemplateTaskDependancies` table. I thought using a modelbuilder configuration class would solve the problem, but I must be missing something.

My domain classes are as follows.

```
[Table("TemplateTaskDependancies")]
public class TemplateTaskDependancy : Dependancy<TemplateTask>,
                                      IDependancy<TemplateTask>
{
    [Column("TaskId")]
    public int TaskId { get; set; }

    [Column("NeededTaskId")]
    public int NeededTaskId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TaskId")]
    public override TemplateTask Task { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("NeededTaskId")]
    public override TemplateTask NeededTask { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Dependancy<T> : LoggedEntity
    where T : LoggedEntity
{
    [Column("TaskId")]
    public int TaskId { get; set; }

    [Column("NeededTaskId")]
    public int NeededTaskId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TaskId")]
    public abstract T Task { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("NeededTaskId")]
    public abstract T NeededTask { get; set; }

}

public interface IDependancy<T> where T : LoggedEntity
{        
    int Id { get; set; }        

    int TaskId { get; set; }

    int NeededTaskId { get; set; }

    T NeededTask { get; set; }

    T Task { get; set; }

    State { get; set; }
}

public abstract class LoggedEntity : IObjectWithState
{
     public int Id { get; set; }  // primary key

     // todo with Julie Lerman's repository pattern
}
```

In my context I have

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   modelBuilder.Conventions
               .Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
   modelBuilder.Configurations
               .Add(new TemplateTaskDependancyConfiguration());
}

public class TemplateTaskDependancyConfiguration :
             EntityTypeConfiguration<TemplateTaskDependancy>
{
    public TemplateTaskDependancyConfiguration()
    {
        HasRequired(x => x.NeededTask)
       .WithMany(y=>y.NeededTasks)
       .HasForeignKey(z=>z.NeededTaskId)
       .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        HasRequired(x => x.NeededTask)
       .WithMany(y => y.Dependancies)
       .HasForeignKey(z => z.TaskId)
       .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        HasRequired(x=>x.Task)
       .WithMany(y=>y.NeededTasks)
       .HasForeignKey(z=>z.NeededTaskId)
       .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        HasRequired(x => x.Task)
       .WithMany(y => y.Dependancies)
       .HasForeignKey(z => z.TaskId)
       .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have no primary key defined anywhere?

By the way, it's dependEncy.

Comment: Oops, I updated LoggedEntity to show it.  *Australian spelling :-)

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the problem was caused by an unneeded collection of

```
public List<TemplateTaskDependancy> Tasks
```

inside my TemplateTask class.

i.e the foreign key table contained an extra collection of objects.